# jquery (JQM) refresh a form element

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to set the default value of a form element by calling some js code, but the input did not seem to get refreshed.

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="defcal">Purchase Date</label>
<input name="defcal" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="defcal"/>
</li>

function onDeviceReady() {
var today = new Date();
var dayofmonth = today.getDate();
var dayofweek = today.getDay();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
var monthstring = month;
if(month < 10){
    monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
}

$('#defcal').val(year+'-'+month+'-'+dayofmonth);
```

}

Someone suggested using $('#defcal').textinput(); to refresh the input but it didn't work either.

Comment: in the above, `$('#defcal').val(year+'-'+month+'-'+dayofmonth);` is not being loaded on DOM ready. You need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Comment: This is in the onDeviceReady function in PhoneGap, which is assumed to replace document.ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check that the `onDocumentReady` function is being called by adding an `alert()` to it or something because this code works in jsfiddle when called as the document ready function or `$(function() { });` block.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p3GbM/

In this example I also set the `#devcal` value using the `monthstring` as it looks like you intended it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Depends when do you want to call this function is it's on some elts change do something like this :

```
    $(function() {
    $('#ID_ELTS').change(function() {

  var today = new Date();
    var dayofmonth = today.getDate();
    var dayofweek = today.getDay();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var monthstring = month;
    if(month < 10){
        monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
    }

    $('#defcal').val(year+'-'+month+'-'+dayofmonth);
    });

});
```